# Python - Is this the correct way to initialize a matrix of empty sets?

Tags: python, dictionary, matrix, set

I'm using this line of code to initialize a matrix of empty sets:

```
table = [[{} for j in range(len(words)+1)] for i in range(len(words))]
```

Is this the correct way?
My IDE (PyCharm) warns me that `j` and `i` are unused, should I ignore this warning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes as you don't use them in your result,you can ignore them and use `_` :

```
table = [[{} for _ in range(len(words)+1)] for _ in range(len(words))]
```

Comment: oh, sweet! i didn't know that Python has an equivalent of Matlab's `~`... thanks! :)